# How to pagination

Tags: php, pagination

How to put pagination in my code. I don't have an idea about putting pages for my data when echoed in the table

```
<?php
 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM utility_readings WHERE readings_type='1'";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set))
 {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
            <td width="20%"><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:edit_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img src="../edit.png" align="center" /></a></td>
        </tr>
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to study about it in tutorials. There are plenty of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain the basic logic behind the pagination.

1. Find the total number of items
2. How many items do you want to show on one page
3. Then divide total number of items by items per page to get the total number of pages
4. Call a function on next and prev buttons to fetch the relevant items. If you are using MySQL query to fetch data. You can use LIMIT option in query to fetch the desired records.

These are basic steps, however, I will recommend you to use some tested script for this purpose. Otherwise, you need to handle all the possible scenarios which will be really complex for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this:

_conn = $conn;
    $this->_query = $query;

    $rs= $this->_conn->query( $this->_query );
    $this->_total = $rs->num_rows;

}

}

And retrieve it like this:

    _limit   = $limit;
    $this->_page    = $page;

    if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
        $query      = $this->_query;
    } else {
        $query      = $this->_query . " LIMIT " . ( ( $this->_page - 1 ) * $this->_limit ) . ", $this->_limit";
    }
    $rs             = $this->_conn->query( $query );

    while ( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $results[]  = $row;
    }

    $result         = new stdClass();
    $result->page   = $this->_page;
    $result->limit  = $this->_limit;
    $result->total  = $this->_total;
    $result->data   = $results;

    return $result;
}

Use this great tutorial in order to fully understand how to paginate with PHP:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928

OR do it in a non OOP way:

       ".
               "EMP NAME : {$row['emp_name']} 
 ".
               EMP SALARY : {$row['emp_salary']} 
 ".
               "--------------------------------
";
         }

         if( $page > 0 )
         {
            $last = $page - 2;
            echo "Last 10 Records |";
            echo "Next 10 Records";
         }

         else if( $page == 0 )
         {
            echo "Next 10 Records";
            }

         else if( $left_rec Last 10 Records";
         }

         mysql_close($conn);
      ?>

Comment: Thanks but I need the ordinary code (without the "-->"). I'm not into it.